# How to convert click coordinates of different dimensions into 320 dimension size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, xpath

I'm too much annoyed to find the solution for converting click coordinates of various device dimension into 320[iPhone 4] screen.

I have all required data like element offset, click offset, window width/height, etc. but not found any proper solution to convert it into 320.

For e.g. I need to convert below mentioned X,Y which I collect from 480 screen:

1. Element offset in x,y [30, 1903]
2. Click offset in x,y [225, 38] // Here I mentioned click offset of element not the document/window.
3. Element width/height(in px) [420, 38]

AND

Below is the result which I expecting after converting this data relative to 320.

[X,Y] = [161, 38]

Can any one help me to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a little ratio math...

```
 var xratio=225/420;   //420-mouse-x-coord divided by 420
 var yratio=38/38;     // mouse-y-coord/element height

var x=320*xratio;
var y=38*yratio;
```

You may have to put x and y values in Math.round() to get a perfect pixel
and not decimal.

EDIT

You'll have to adjust it based on what all your offsets are (I used 225, but you may have to add or subtract your 30 element offset to the 225 first BEFORE dividing by 420 to get the ratio percentage depending on how you are summing all your offsets)

To reverse engineer what you want you can use cross multiplication or simple algebra:

161 is to 320, what x is to 420;

(161/320)=(x/420)

0.503125=(x/420)

0.503125*420=x

211.3125=x;

Your x coordinate would have to be 211.3125 on a 420 width object to be proportionally the same as as 161 on a 320 width object;

ALSO:

For anyone who might be trying to do this for web applications, 
getBoundingClientRect() is way easier then dealing with all the various offset properties.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: If I applied this equation I didn't get exact or near to expected result.

Comment: Oops forgot something. Try it now.

Comment: Seems okay with example data, but if I applied on [103, 38] then again result is wrong so might be some thing else we need to calculate. One more thing you used screen size to calculate the X, I guess their might be width of element instead and width of element is 290px in 320 dimension, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yeah, you y want to use the width of the element, if that is what you are basing your local coordinates on.