# Get Image clicked position on DIfferent Resolution when the coordinates will be changed on different devices

Tags: image, get, click, position

I have a responsive Image which is working on different mobile resolution.
I want to Ask you, when I clicked on image at any place like top-left, left-botton etc, I want to get its(image) position.Means On which position it is being clicked. I tried the following scenario While Implementation of my Source Code, I get a coordinate on particular place on which The image is clicked.

Problem: Each of Mobile device has different resolution, So, For the same scenario, the coordinate will be differed. I required the implementation like the place of clicked image should be same on every resolution.

please tell me how can I resolve my Issues, And which one is best technology, tell me if anyone has knowledge to resolve this.

Comment: What is the coding language you are using; please post your working code.

Comment: Kindly tell me in any language like in javascript, jquery , angular etc. My Code is Not working. KIndly implement from ur end.

Answer (score 0):

There have been some previous posts that try to achieve what you want, the basic logic can be achieved by calculating ratio:

```
var xratio=225/420;   // 420-mouse-x-coord divided by 420
var yratio=38/38;     // mouse-y-coord/element height

var x=320*xratio;
var y=38*yratio;
```

Please see the following references:

[How to convert click coordinates of different dimensions into 320 dimension size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29762748/how-to-convert-click-coordinates-of-different-dimensions-into-320-dimension-size)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: Can you Please explain me? and write the whole precedure.